# How to validate properly an image upload

Tags: php, validation, exif

Currently I am trying to validate image upload by determining file mime type using `getimagesize()`. For better performance I also used `exif_imagetype()`.

Both the methods are not completely foolproof to validate an image and can be exploitable and I know how.

Please let me know if anybody have a better solution than the above two.

Comment: This is not an answer to your specific question so I'll make it a comment instead. I always make a copy of the uploaded file using `imagecopyfromjpeg()` (or apparopriate) in case of nasty data.

Comment: what about making a copy and comparing md5 hash ?

Comment: @ShumailMohy-ud-Din — The whole point of using `imagecopyfromjpeg` is that it re-encodes the image data so the file is different and any exploits are removed, so `md5`ing it would fail.

Comment: @Quentin : I see, you are correct

Comment: So the only thing I can find is to create complete new image using `imagecreatefromjpeg()` which I am already using as I can't find any function like `imagecopyfromjpeg()`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$type = mime_content_type($filename); 
if (strstr($type, 'image/')) {
    echo 'This is  an  image';
}
```

Comment: That function is deprecated. What makes you think it is less exploitable than the methods used in the question anyway?